# Programmatically load the page variant being used on path or node object

Tags: 8, panels

I'm attempting to be able to load a page variant given a specific path. My ultimate goal is to loop through all the links in a menu, find out what page_manager variant is being used and load the context data from that variant. I'm able to grab the data just fine if I manually supply a page id. Below is me obtaining the data from the about page I've created in page manager.

```
$page_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('page');
$variant_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('page_variant');
$about = $page_storage->load('about');
$about_variant = $about->getVariants();
$about_variant = reset($about_variant);
foreach($about_variant->getContexts() as $context){
    $label = $context->getContextDefinition()->getLabel();
    if($label == 'Icon'){
        var_dump($context->getContextValue());
    }
}
```

This works just fine. But what if I want to load the context data of each link in a menu? These are links that I can't anticipate. Also some of these links will be regular pages and some will be actual nodes that also have their own variant.

I can load the nodes from the route like so

```
$params = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromUserInput($path)->getRouteParameters();
if (isset($params['node'])) {
    $node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($params['node']);
    //We have a node which I don't know how to get the variant of
} else {
    //We have a regular page that I don't know obtain the id of
}
```

But even though I have the node I have no idea of a way to interface with it in a way that allows me to obtain the page variant I'm using. If it's a regular page, then as long as I have the page id of it I can load the page variant like I have done before, but I don't know how to obtain that.

So ultimately I suppose I need to be able to programmatically obtain two things

- How to obtain the page id from a page given its path
- How to see the page variant being used on a node

UPDATE: I did manage to obtain the page with this line

```
$page = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('page')->loadByProperties(['path' => $link]);
```

Still not sure how to grab the variant the node is using yet though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the variant being used by the node I was able to retrieve the info inside the array returned by

```
$node->panelizer->getValue()
```

And to get the page I used

```
$page = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('page')->loadByProperties(['path' => $link]);
```